# IdentifierForVendor value under certain scenario

Tags: ios, iphone

I am developing an App using UIDevice`s IdentifierForValue to track user`s behavior.  In the present we know that under the scenarion shown below, value of IdentifierForVendor will change:

1. App uninstall and install again

As we know that for mobile device, there`re some scenario that we need to take into consideration. So how about the value of IdentifierForVendor in the following circumstances:

1. If subscriber change one`s SIM but still using the same phone
2. If subscriber use the same SIM but change to another phone. For example, one stop using iphone 6 and use iphone 6S instead with data restored from iTune`s backup data.

If subscriber use another Apple ID in the same phone.
Any ideas? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`identifierForVendor` doesn't take into account the SIM card or Apple ID. It is alternative to UDID that doesn't allow tracking specific device and it is constant for device until every app of the vendor on that device is uninstalled. I used this identifier and switched SIM and Apple ID in the past and I didn't notice the identifier changing.

[Link to the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDevice_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIDevice/identifierForVendor)